# How to match a string in another string without using indexOf?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Let's just say I have two strings, `a` & `b`.

```
var a = 'john.smith@yahoo.com';
var b = 'yahoo12345556';
```

What I am expecting is result would be `yahoo` but using `a.indexOf(b)` would give me `-1`.

If I change `b` to `yahoo` & do `a.indexOf(b)`, it obviously wouldn't give me `-1`.

Should I match characters in a loop instead? But the two strings aren't of equal length. It's also important that the characters should be in sequence, I am not looking for occurrence of characters.

Comment: so find a substring that's common between the two variables?

Comment: What is your criteria for match? Longest matching substring between both?

Comment: Exactly, irrespective of the position of the searched string in the original string.

Comment: the problem with your problem is that the potential intersection is large... the o on yahoo is also part of john, just like the h in yahoo is part of smith, etc.

Comment: @juvian Yes, yep exactly that too.

Comment: What do you want with `12345556`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: @TheProHands It should ignore `12345556`, since only `yahoo` matches with the original string.

Comment: what should be the result for this inputs: `var a = 'john.smith@yahoo.com';
var b = 'yahoo10com22smi@';` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I ask the same. I didn't still get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your are looking for [Longest Common Substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) problem.
Here is a [good javascript implementation](http://www.graemeboy.com/longest-common-subsequence) with explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use recursion to solve this problem:

```
function findLongestCommon (a, b, len) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length-1; i=i+len) {
        var sub = a.substring(i, len)
        if (len == 0){
            return "";
        }
        else if (sub.indexOf(b) != -1) {
            return a;
        }
        else{
            return findLongestCommon(a, b, len-1);
        }
}
```

By calling findLongestCommon(a, b, a.length) you will be able to go through every combination of letter starting with the largest (the whole string) to the smallest (one letter) and if no letter is found it will return empty string.

Comment: In the question title: "*without using indexOf*".

Comment: @hatchet I dont think the user meant "without using indexOf" but rather "I tried indexOf and it didn't work, any better ideas?". The easiest and quickest way to accomplish the goal is through the use of recursion and indexOf. If you have a better answer then post it.